# Is it okay to have a LOT of null values in MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure how to word this perfectly, but let me give it a try. I am working on building an inventory control application to be used with many different customers to do everything from check their own stock of items, get prices, order product, etc. The front-end is in Flex (Flash Builder), and the back end is MySQL and PHP. So - here's the real question I guess. When the customer places an order for product I am not sure how many of what they are ordering, but I need to save all items onto one 'ticket'. (Example: One order might be for 2 apples, 3 oranges, a banana, and a kiwi - The next might just order one apple.) So in my 'tickets' database I have space in there for up to 20 items (ticketItem1, ticketItem2, etc...) - The obvious drawback here is that if the customer only orders one product I am left with 19 empty spaces.

What types of problems, if any, are normally associated with having a lot of NULL values in a database? Is there a way to help prevent them from happening? And is there any suggestions to help aid in this?

Also and finally - Each item ordered (let's use an apple again) has it's own UNIQUE bar code associated with it. So one apple might be numbered 0001, and another may be 4524...

Thank you for any assistance you can offer.

-CS

Comment: Why can't you use an 1:n relation to store orders and ordered items?

Comment: Read up on [Database Normalization](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/).

Comment: You shouldn't do it this way. You should add another table called `orderItems` or something, with the ID of the order in it - this way you can have infinite products per order, it's much easier to manage and it's in a swanky one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of having 20 columns `ticketItem1, ticketItem2, ...`, introduce a table `order_item`, like this:

Table **order**:

```
id customer
1  42
2  23
```

Table **item**:

```
id name
1  banana
2  kiwi
3  apple
4  oranges
```

Table **order_item**:

```
order_id item_id multiplicity
1        1       1             # 1 banana
1        2       1             # 1 kiwi
1        3       2             # 2 apples
1        4       3             # 3 oranges
2        3       1             # 1 apple in the second order
```

Then, [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JOIN) over the tables to get all ordered items in an order.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a table that lists the Order, and one for the OrderDetails with an OrderID pointing to the Order table

So if you have 10 products in an order. You will have 1 row in Order, and 10 in OrderDetails

Comment: So if I understand this correctly - I will still have a lot of null values, they will just be in a separate table that calls out which specific product was requested for that 'ticket'. What is the benefit of doing it this way versus the other? - I'll read more about DB Normalization also. However - there will be ~30-50 orders/tickets per day...I appreciate the help!

Comment: Not really. You have 1 table that lists all the order, without the tickets. You have for exemple in this table the following columns : ID, OrderDate, IsProcessed, and on another table OrderItems : ID, OrderID, Ticket, and any other columns for specific information for 1 ticket. 

If you have one order with 20 tickets. You will have 1 entry in the table Orders, and 20 entries in OrderDetails. And there will be no NULL values in any columns

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be dynamic in what you store, you **could** use a json array. I fully agree with the others that database normalization is the first thing todo. I would follow Codd's rules.

But in case you don't know exactly what you need to store json might be a solution. One **major** drawback however is that searching is getting pretty difficult.